# How do I calculate the product of the difference of consecutive pairs?

Tags: haskell

I have to calculate the product between the difference of each consecutive pair from a list with this function definition `f :: [Int] -> Int`, for example:

```
f [3, 1, 4, 2, 5] = (3 - 1) * (1 - 4) * (4 - 2) * (2 - 5) 
                  = 36
```

I have to do this recursively, I know how to do the product of the elements in the array, but how do I select tuples from the list and multiply the difference of them with the next tuple's difference, any tips would be appreciated. So far I have this:

```
f :: [Int] -> Int
f [] = 1
f (x:xs) = x * f xs
```

but this only gives me the product of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Note: This post is written in [literate Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming). You can save it as ListProduct.lhs and try it in your GHCi.</sub>

---

In order to fix your function, we have to consider some cases. First of all, what should happen if the list is empty? We return `1`:

```
> f :: [Int] -> Int
> f [] = 1
```

Now, we have to think about lists with more elements. For example the list could have at least one element:

```
f (x:xs) = ...
```

However, this isn't really helpful. We need *two* consecutive elements in order to subtract them from each other. However, we can do so by pattern match the remaining list again:

```
f (x : (y : xs))
```

which is the same as `f (x : y : xs)` since `(:)` is right associative. We end up with:

```
> f (x : y : xs) = (x - y) * f rest
```

What's the rest? It cannot be `xs`. If we would use `xs`, we wouldn't get the correct result in the following case:

```
f [1,2,3,4] = (1 - 2) * f [3,4]
            = (1 - 2) * (3 - 4) * f []
            --      ^^^^^^ 
            --      (2 - 3) is missing!
```

So `rest` needs to have both `y` *and* `xs`:

```
>      where rest = y : xs
```

We can confirm that this works as intended:

```
f [1,2,3,4] = (1 - 2) * f [2,3,4]
            = (1 - 2) * (2 - 3) * f [3,4]
            = (1 - 2) * (2 - 3) * (3 - 4) * f [4]
```

Therefore, the case where we have at least two elements is handled correctly.

What about lists where we have only one element? Well, with one element, you cannot subtract another. And as you can see above, we will always end up with `f [x]` for some `x` at one point. Therefore a sensible choice is `f [x] = 1`:

```
f [a] = 1
```

However, since we don't actually about that element, we can use `_` as a *wildcard*:

```
> f _ = 1
```

Note that this is the same result as for `f []`. So we could have written `f` as

```
f :: [Int] -> Int
f (x : y : xs) = (x - y) * f (y : xs)
f _            = 1
```

but that's up to you.

#### Exercises

- Write a function that returns `True` for a list with exactly two elements. Don't use `length`, use pattern matching only.
- Write a function that returns `True` for a list with at least four elements and `False` otherwise. Use pattern matching only, no other functions.
- Write a function that returns the sum of triple consecutive products, e.g.

  ```
  f [1,2,3,4,5] = (1 * 2 * 3) + (2 * 3 * 4) + (3 * 4 * 5)
  ```

Comment: amazing, I understand now, brilliantly explained, thank you.

Comment: one question tho, `f _ = 1` means that "a list exactly with one number" ?

Comment: @southpaw93: It's a wild card. You don't actually care whether it has one or multiple entries. But since pattern gets matched from top to bottom, there's only one case left. Edited my answer.

Comment: and when we call `f  (y : xs)` we get a tail of the previous array ?

Answer (score 5):

Create an intermediate structure with pairs

```
a = [3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
zip a (tail a)
```

or better use

```
zipWith (-) a (tail a)
```

which will give you the diffs and continue with the product.

If you need to implement your own recursive solution you need to consume input elements two by two.  Base case should be easy you have to consider the null case and single element case (might be the same!)

Additional hint, write your function for this base case

```
f (x:y:xs) = (x-y) * f ???
```

and this terminal cases (might be combined if same behavior).

```
f [] = ???
f [x] = ???
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm aiming for, my own recursive solution, I am currently trying to wrap my head around how it could be, I just don't understand how I can consume two by two elements from the array...

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
import Data.List

f l = product [a-b | (a:b:_) <- tails l ]
```

The function works as follows: `tails` generates - as the name suggests - all tails of the given list `l`, so for `[3, 1, 4, 2, 5]`, that's `[[3,1,4,2,5],[1,4,2,5],[4,2,5],[2,5],[5],[]]`. Now we do pattern matching with `(a:b:_)` which means that only lists that contains at least two items will be considered, and furthermore the first two elements unify with `a` and `b`. Now we generate a new list with `a-b`. Thus the list for `[3,1,4,2,5]` is `[2,-3,2,-3]`. Now you simply take the product.

**EDIT**

The signature of `f` is `Num a => [a] -> a` which is more generic than `[Int] -> Int`. You can thus simply downcast it by:

```
import Data.List

f :: [Int] -> Int
f l = product [a-b | (a:b:_) <- tails l ]
```

Comment: I have to respect the given function definition : `f :: [Int] -> Int`

Comment: @southpaw93: that's no problem, you can simply downcast it. This `f` is more generic.

Answer (score 0):

While zipping is often easier for this kind of problem, folding works, too:

```
f (x:xs) = fst $ foldl (\(p,n) m -> (p*(n-m),m)) (1,x) xs
```